# Enums with variable index

Tags: php, oop, enums

I'm not sure what the correct wording of my question is, but I added an `enum` (`NP_PostTypeType`) because I need to know what the type of each item in my initial enum (`NP_PostType`) is.

I store the current PostType in `$postType` which gets fed into a method and now in that method I need to extract the type for each type.

What I tried doing was: `switch(NP_PostTypeType::$type)`, but this yields: `Fatal error: Access to undeclared static property: NP_PostTypeType::$type`

These are my 2 enums:

```
abstract class NP_PostType extends BasicEnum {
    const Event = "event";
    const Job = "job";
    const Quote = "quote";
    const Status = "status";
    const Video = "video";
}

abstract class NP_PostTypeType extends BasicEnum {
    const Event = "type";
    const Job = "type";
    const Quote = "format";
    const Status = "format";
    const Video = "format";
}
```

How do I go about this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't access a constant like you do with a static property, the [constant](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.constant.php) function is your solution :

```
$type = constant('NP_PostTypeType::' . $postType);
```

But be careful, your `$postType` case must match your `NP_PostTypeType` constant names (currently not the case), you should update your NP_PostType class to :

```
abstract class NP_PostType extends BasicEnum {
    const Event = "Event";
    const Job = "Job";
    const Quote = "Quote";
    const Status = "Status";
    const Video = "Video";
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but the string values in the `NP_PostType` enum are values that match data coming from the database, so they need to stay the same. Or should I perhaps create a "parent" enum like the one you mentioned and then rename the `NP_PostType` to `NP_PostTypeKeys`?

Comment: Just applying `ucfirst` on `$postType` might just do, no need for another class... unless your string values from the db are more complexe.

Comment: The code I posted was only partial though, there is also 'AboutUs' => 'about-us'. I don't think any string replacements are a very elegant solution here? (also I'm trying to improve my OOP and find the best solution)

Answer (score 1):

Try converting expression to string: `switch(constant("NP_PostTypeType::$type"))`

Answer (score 1):

Use *[constant](https://www.php.net/constant)*,

```
$constant = "Event";
$classname = "NP_PostType";
$variable = $classname.'::'.$constant;
echo constant($variable); //event
```

**[Working Demo](http://codepad.viper-7.com/f2TU0e)**.

Comment: Thanks, there's actually a design flaw in my code because I get the `NP_PostType` earlier in the code and store it in a var, but e.g. `NP_PostType::Quote` yields "quote", so now I'm trying to get `NP_PostTypeType::$type`, which is the same as `NP_PostTypeType::quote` and thus not a match. Could you suggest a better solution for me?

Comment: Use [ucfirst](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ucfirst.php) funtcion to capitalized your first letter of a constant.

Comment: The code I posted was only partial though, there is also 'AboutUs' => 'about-us'. I don't think any string replacements are a very elegant solution here? (also I'm trying to improve my OOP and find the best solution)